# How to temporarily stop syncing Dropbox

Tags: ubuntu, dropbox

Is there way to stop syncing the Dropbox folder without deleting Dropbox from my computer?
I want to stop while I'm not in home and have only expensive Internet.

I can pause it, but when I switch on my laptop again, Dropbox resumes syncing. I am on Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do couple of things:

- Disable it completely.

[image: Start Dropbox on system startup]

- Limit the download/upload bandwidth rates.

[image: Download/upload rates]

Answer (score 4):

Another and perhaps quicker option is to pause syncing for as long as you need to. It works flawlessly on the recent stable and beta versions on Windows, so it should work the same under Ubuntu.

Right click on Dropbox's tray icon and select Pause syncing, as shown in the following screen capture.

[image]

Comment: read the question please: "I can pause it, but when I switch on my laptop again, Dropbox resumes syncing."